# How to link to prev/next entry depending on related data?

Tags: relations, previous-next

I am quite new to Craft and I am not sure how to get a prev/next link only for entries with related data in a specific field.

My situation:
I have a Structure (let's call it `sourceEntry`) with an optional field (can be empty or can have related data, let's call this one `relatedData`). That field is of type entries. So `sourceEntry` is related to other entries (I'll call them `targetEntry`).

Assuming I am on the entry's detail page (so, my `sourceEntry` object is just accessible via `entry` in my twig template) I would do this to link to previous/next entry:

`{% set criteria = {section: 'sourceEntry' } %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
{% set next = entry.getNext(criteria) %}
{# …and then just insert the links… #}`

But in my case I need to get the prev/next entry that has set `relatedData` respectively I'd link to the prev/next entry that is related to `targetEntry`.

Example:
I have five entries of type `sourceEntry`: A, B, C, D, E.
The `relatedData` field for two of them is empty: B, C.
The others are related to posts of type `targetEntry`: A, D, E.
When loading the detail page for A there should be a next link to D, on detail page for D there should be a next link to E and a prev link to A and so on.

How am I able to achieve this? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

This is the solution for those who are too lazy to click the link in Bob Olde Hampsink's answer:

`{% set criteria = {section: 'sourceEntry', relatedTo: craft.users } %}
{% set prev = entry.getPrev(criteria) %}
{% set next = entry.getNext(criteria) %}
{# …and then just insert the links… #}`

I feel kind of dumb now not even been trying this on my own before (although I knew about relations, but I wasn't sure how to set the criteria object properly). Thanks, Bob Olde Hampsink!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the [`relatedTo`](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/relations#the-relatedTo-param) param to your criteria